# parLapply returns NULL instead of the correct output from a for loop

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, parallel-processing

When I am using parLapply for the below loop the output is returned as NULL. Assuming to original data set looks similar to this.

```
datacut<-structure(list(time = c(270, 330, 270, 250, 280, 500, 260, 280, 
250, 320, 280, 410, 270, 330, 190, 330, 310, 300, 300, 260, 110, 
250, 120, 330, 240, 220, 110, 400, 190, 200, 260, 320, 140, 140, 
150, 200, 310, 190, 410, 120, 360, 410, 380, 310, 330, 360, 370, 
320, 370, 330, 550, 430, 290, 380, 350, 250, 380, 370, 440, 420, 
300, 230, 300, 100, 220, 300, 260, 290, 230, 210, 200, 390, 290, 
210, 160, 350, 190, 310, 210, 250, 150, 250, 200, 230, 220, 300, 
180, 240, 180, 240, 300, 350, 210, 50, 110, 270, 220, 200, 260, 
190), who = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
20L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L), x = c(987.353265152362, 570.817987386894, 
1147.5681499552, 637.526076016409, 1439.13510253106, 1396.6452808061, 
1089.52981013637, 1362.12233458255, 1826.91526170041, 519.27011734849, 
1944.37086699462, 163.828901387395, 536.540090534885, 842.072125881062, 
806.786349357875, 547.493800081537, 1530.05438629783, 1187.4877646876, 
1164.22578558938, 1332.15300245153, 987.353265152362, 570.817987386894, 
1147.5681499552, 637.526076016409, 1439.13510253106, 1396.6452808061, 
1089.52981013637, 1362.12233458255, 1826.91526170041, 519.27011734849, 
1944.37086699462, 163.828901387395, 536.540090534885, 842.072125881062, 
806.786349357875, 547.493800081537, 1530.05438629783, 1187.4877646876, 
1164.22578558938, 1332.15300245153, 987.353265152362, 570.817987386894, 
1147.5681499552, 637.526076016409, 1439.13510253106, 1396.6452808061, 
1089.52981013637, 1362.12233458255, 1826.91526170041, 519.27011734849, 
1944.37086699462, 163.828901387395, 536.540090534885, 842.072125881062, 
806.786349357875, 547.493800081537, 1530.05438629783, 1187.4877646876, 
1164.22578558938, 1332.15300245153, 987.353265152362, 570.817987386894, 
1147.5681499552, 637.526076016409, 1439.13510253106, 1396.6452808061, 
1089.52981013637, 1362.12233458255, 1826.91526170041, 519.27011734849, 
1944.37086699462, 163.828901387395, 536.540090534885, 842.072125881062, 
806.786349357875, 547.493800081537, 1530.05438629783, 1187.4877646876, 
1164.22578558938, 1332.15300245153, 987.353265152362, 570.817987386894, 
1147.5681499552, 637.526076016409, 1439.13510253106, 1396.6452808061, 
1089.52981013637, 1362.12233458255, 1826.91526170041, 519.27011734849, 
1944.37086699462, 163.828901387395, 536.540090534885, 842.072125881062, 
806.786349357875, 547.493800081537, 1530.05438629783, 1187.4877646876, 
1164.22578558938, 1332.15300245153), y = c(1802.08232812874, 
349.336242713164, 1789.49467712533, 361.611973188148, 1492.44148360367, 
1459.91771610835, 1747.54778561385, 307.446170665141, 1537.06857132815, 
1695.52960638677, 1712.66523384926, 848.740501405309, 1767.75113718326, 
892.263991723806, 882.114397627208, 851.366759631443, 289.310647206991, 
1194.78394174711, 538.09973824101, 1599.70219032337, 1802.08232812874, 
349.336242713164, 1789.49467712533, 361.611973188148, 1492.44148360367, 
1459.91771610835, 1747.54778561385, 307.446170665141, 1537.06857132815, 
1695.52960638677, 1712.66523384926, 848.740501405309, 1767.75113718326, 
892.263991723806, 882.114397627208, 851.366759631443, 289.310647206991, 
1194.78394174711, 538.09973824101, 1599.70219032337, 1802.08232812874, 
349.336242713164, 1789.49467712533, 361.611973188148, 1492.44148360367, 
1459.91771610835, 1747.54778561385, 307.446170665141, 1537.06857132815, 
1695.52960638677, 1712.66523384926, 848.740501405309, 1767.75113718326, 
892.263991723806, 882.114397627208, 851.366759631443, 289.310647206991, 
1194.78394174711, 538.09973824101, 1599.70219032337, 1802.08232812874, 
349.336242713164, 1789.49467712533, 361.611973188148, 1492.44148360367, 
1459.91771610835, 1747.54778561385, 307.446170665141, 1537.06857132815, 
1695.52960638677, 1712.66523384926, 848.740501405309, 1767.75113718326, 
892.263991723806, 882.114397627208, 851.366759631443, 289.310647206991, 
1194.78394174711, 538.09973824101, 1599.70219032337, 1802.08232812874, 
349.336242713164, 1789.49467712533, 361.611973188148, 1492.44148360367, 
1459.91771610835, 1747.54778561385, 307.446170665141, 1537.06857132815, 
1695.52960638677, 1712.66523384926, 848.740501405309, 1767.75113718326, 
892.263991723806, 882.114397627208, 851.366759631443, 289.310647206991, 
1194.78394174711, 538.09973824101, 1599.70219032337), metricrel = c(2.011, 
2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 
2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 
2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 
2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 
2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 
2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 
2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 
2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 
2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 
2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 
2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 2.011
), sim = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L)), row.names = c(NA, -100L), groups = structure(list(
    sim = 1:5, .rows = structure(list(1:20, 21:40, 41:60, 61:80, 
        81:100), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The loop without parallelisation works fine, giving the desired output.

```
for (sim in unique(datacut$sim)){ 
  #print(paste("For ",sim))
  res <- NULL
  stti<-sample(1:10,1)
  infmax<-max(datacut$time)
  samp.time <- seq(from = stti, to = infmax, by = 10) 
  temp <- datacut[datacut$sim==sim,]
 
for (t in samp.time){
    test <- sample(temp$who, 10,replace=FALSE)
    #print(paste("Id",test))
    
   
    inf.time <- temp[temp$who %in% test, "time"]
    #print(paste("at time",inf.time))
    m <- sum(inf.time <= t) 
    q <- mean(temp$time<=t)
    res <- rbind(res, data.frame(sim, m, q, t=t, n))
    if (m>=1){
     break
    }
  }
}
```

This creates the data frame res, which looks like this (will be slightly difference each time).

```
res<-structure(list(sim = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L), m = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), q = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.05, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.05, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.05, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.05, 0.05), t = c(2, 
12, 22, 32, 42, 52, 62, 72, 82, 92, 102, 112, 122, 132, 142, 
152, 162, 172, 182, 192, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 
100, 110, 8, 18, 28, 38, 48, 58, 68, 78, 88, 98, 108, 118, 128, 
138, 148, 158, 168, 178, 188, 198, 208, 218, 228, 238, 248, 258, 
8, 18, 28, 38, 48, 58, 68, 78, 88, 98, 108, 8, 18, 28, 38, 48, 
58, 68), n = c(20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 
20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 
20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 
20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 
20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20)), row.names = c(NA, 
-75L), class = "data.frame")
```

However, when I try to run this for loop using the parLapply, I return NULL. Here is the code I am using.

```
sur_par_func <- function(i=NULL){
for (sim in unique(datacut$sim)){ 
  #print(paste("For ",sim))
  res <- NULL
  stti<-sample(1:10,1)
  infmax<-max(datacut$time)
  samp.time <- seq(from = stti, to = infmax, by = 10) 
  temp <- datacut[datacut$sim==sim,]
 
for (t in samp.time){
    test <- sample(temp$who, 10,replace=FALSE)
    #print(paste("Id",test))
    
   
    inf.time <- temp[temp$who %in% test, "time"]
    #print(paste("at time",inf.time))
    m <- sum(inf.time <= t) 
    q <- mean(temp$time<=t)
    res <- rbind(res, data.frame(sim, m, q, t=t, n))
    if (m>=1){
     break
    }
  }
}
cl <- makeCluster(mc <- getOption("cl.cores", 3))
clusterExport(cl=cl, varlist=c("datacut"),envir = environment())
par_sur<-parLapply(1,fun=sur_par_func,cl=cl)
stopCluster(cl)
```

The output for par_sur is NULL. What am I doing incorrectly to not get the desired output?

Comment: It's because your function `sur_par_func()` returns NULL. You will get the exact same result if you call `par_sur <- lapply(1, FUN = sur_par_func)`.  Focus on fixing the `lapply()` case first.  Only then worry about parallelization.  You need to write the function so that it returns a value.  Your function must not rely on side effects such as assuming it can update global variables. Specifically, you cannot use `res <- rbind(res, ...)` inside a function.  Again, this is _not_ specific to parallel processing - it's the nature of functions and functional languages like R.

Comment: With the risk of sidetracking you to my comment above, you might find https://www.jottr.org/2019/01/11/parallelize-a-for-loop-by-rewriting-it-as-an-lapply-call/ useful too (I'm the author).

Comment: Thank you for the specific guidance in your comment. I am reading through your blog/tutorial now, very interesting and I think relevant. Thank you.

Comment: I have tried creating a lapply function that does not modify the global environment: ````results<-datacut %>% group_by(sim) %>%
lapply(datacut, function(){
samp.time <- seq(from = sample(1:10,1), to = max(datacut$time), by = 10)
for (t in samp.time){
  test <- sample(df$who,20,replace = FALSE) 
  inf.time<-datacut[datacut$who %in% test, "time"]
  m <-sum(inf.time <= t)
  q<-mean(df$time<=t)
  if (m>=1){
    break
  }
} 
}
  )```` But I am returning the error: Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : argument "df2" is missing, with no default. Any suggestions?